# Segmentation fault in C with dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, segmentation-fault

Please help me find an error in dynamic memory allocation.

It is necessary to print all the words that begin and end with one letter.

The algorithm works with a static array, but there is an error when trying to create a dynamic array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int len = 0;
    char str[10] = "aba cd geg ";
    char* word = NULL;
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    while(str[i]!='\0')
        {
            if(!isspace(str[i]))
            {
                n++;
                word = (char*)realloc(word, (n* sizeof(char)));
                word[j] = str[i];
                j++;
                len++;
            }
            else
            {
                if(word[0] == word[len-1])
                {
                    j = 0;
                    while(j < len)
                    {
                        printf("%c", word[j]);
                        j++;
                    }
                }
                j = 0;
                len = 0;
                free(word);
                n = 0;
            }
            i++;
        }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: can i know what is the output you want to get?

Comment: You forgit to include `#include <ctype.h>`. Compile with all warnings enabled and consider them as errors. And `char str[10] = "aba cd geg ";`, there is not enough space in `str` you forgot about the NUL string terminator, just use `char str[] = "aba cd geg ";` and let the compiler figure out the required size. There may be more errors though.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) Please consistently indent the code.  Indent AFTER every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: regarding: `word = (char*)realloc(word, (n* sizeof(char)));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that cast.  2) When calling `realloc()`, always assign to a temp variable.  Then check (!=NULL) and if not NULL, then assign to the target variable.  Otherwise, the original pointer is lost, resulting in a memory leak.  3) the parameter is expected to be of type `size_t`, not `int`, so this statement: `int n=0;` should be: `size_t n=0;`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: OT:  regarding: `word = (char*)realloc(word, (n* sizeof(char)));`  The expression `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C language as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have freed `word`, you need to set `word` to `NULL`, because `realloc` can only be performed on a NULL pointer or on a valid pointer that has previously been returned by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.

```
  ...
  len = 0;
  free(word);    // after this line, word is no more a valid pointer
  word = NULL;   // <<<< insert this
  n = 0;
  ...
```

In other words this pattern is always wrong:

```
 free(foobar);
 foobar = realloc(foobar, ...);
```

Another possibility is not to free `word` at all and let the next `realloc` take care of it, which in this case is most likely more efficient.

```
  ...
  len = 0;
  // free(word);     remove this line
  n = 0;
  ...
```

but then you need to call `free(word);` at the end of the program, just before `return 0;`

So the end of your program would look like this:

```
      ...
      j = 0;
      len = 0;
      n = 0;
    }
    i++;
  }

  free(word);
  return 0;
```